# Problem getting data from a JSON with Flutter Dart

Tags: php, mysql, flutter, dart

I have problems in the following function, I am trying to display information from a Json, obtained from a database with Flutter and PHP. Apparently, they tell me that it is a type problem, but I don't know how to solve it.

My function is returning a string and they tell me that I have to convert it to a list, I show you the code I have:

```
import "dart:convert";

import "package:flutter/material.dart";
import "package:flutter_application_db/models/todo_model.dart";
import "package:scoped_model/scoped_model.dart";
import "package:http/http.dart" as http;

mixin TodoModel on Model {
  final List<Todo> _todos = [];

  final url = Uri.parse("http://192.168.1.66/api_rest/query/sql_get_all.php");

  List<Todo> get todo => List.from(_todos);

  void fetchTodos() async {
    try {
      final http.Response response = await http.get(
        url,
      );

      final List<dynamic> responseDecoded = json.decode(response.body);

      debugPrint("The response decoded: $responseDecoded");
    } catch (e) {
      print("The error: $e");
    }

    //print(response);
  }
}
```

The error is the following:

```
I/flutter (25473): The error: FormatException: Unexpected character (at character 1)
I/flutter (25473): Connected[{"id":"1","taskId":"1","todoInfo":"Productos Autos"},{"id":"2","t...
I/flutter (25473): ^
```

I'm trying to do the following tutorial to connect Flutter with a PHP+MySQL API: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ur01swlehug&list=PLbd9-9nbCzE6z0hRtWhmarbhfxuuF9XaL&index=10

Any idea how I can resolve this?
Regards.

Comment: Why does the string start with "Connected".  That's not JSON.

Comment: can you post the actual structure if the json data you expect

Comment: It has been fixed, the error was the one mentioned andal Schwartz, the word "Connected" was causing the conflict. He just had to remove it :( Thank you both for your time!